# setting annotation attributes in spring xml

Tags: java, spring

I have been trying to set the `logTime` attribute in my annotation in the spring xml. I am seeing that this is not as easy as I first thought.

```
@Component
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecTime {

public boolean logTime() default true;      
}
```

I have tried to use the `@Value` annotation with the interface with no luck:

```
I)

  @Component
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface LogExecTime {
    @Value("#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}")
public boolean logTime() default true;      
  }
```

and also

```
II)    
 @LogExecTime(logTime=@Value("#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}"))
```

Any ideas how I can do this at xml level or is this not possible with annotation dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah -- that's not ever going to work.

```
@LogExecTime(logTime=@Value("#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}"))
```

will never even compile.  Annotations are not executable code, they're just markers -- extra bit of information that are inserted into the class file whole sale.

You could either put this:

```
@Value("#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}")
boolean logTime = true;
```

As a real field on a spring managed bean somewhere, or have  change your annotation to be like:

```
@Component
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecTime {

    public String logTime() default "true";
}
```

and have whatever is processing that annotation at run time also accept a spring EL expression and resolve it appropriately, and your component would look like this:

```
@LogExecTime(logTime = "#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}")
public class SomeComponent {

    // blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: Hi Iscoughlin. <code>@Value("#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}")
boolean logTime = true; </code> does not work inside an annotation for me, but the <code>logTime = "#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}"</code> looks like it could. My Aspect reads it in but just prints "#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}" and not the value "true" that I set in the xml. Could you show me how you would achieve this?

Comment: You need to do something with the value assigned to the annotation.  In this case, the value is 

#{ConfigureAnnotation.doLogging}

So you need to either instantiate a spring EL resolver to resolve the value or parse the key out your self and so something with it, like System.getProperty( annotation.value().substring(2,annotation.value().size() -3 )